# How to send data to already existing fragment

Tags: java, android, runtime

so I am trying to pass data from one fragment to another.
The navigation would be the following:
fragment1 -> fragment2 -> fragment1
essentially I am sending some data from fragment1 to fragment2 and after the user completes the data I want to send back, I am sending the completed data from fragment2 back to fragment1.

To send data from fragment1 to fragment2 I am using(working code, data is recieved in fragment2):

```
                        //package image uri
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("imageURI", result.toString());

                        //navigate to image display and set title with parceled uri
                        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(view);
                        navController.navigate(R.id.pickedImageFragment, bundle);
```

To send data back from fragment2 to fragment1(not working code):

```
                //create the gotten image class
                String photoName = binding.photoDescription.getText().toString().trim();
                String imageID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                Image myImage = new Image(imageID, photoName, imageUri);

                //bundle it
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("IMAGE", gson.toJson(myImage));

                //send the bundled image on it's way
                NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(view);
                navController.navigate(R.id.ThirdFragment, bundle);
```

And on he recieving end I have:

```
                Gson gson = new Gson();
            
                if (gson.fromJson(requireArguments().getString("IMAGE"), Image.class) != null) {
                    Image myImage = gson.fromJson(requireArguments().getString("IMAGE"), Image.class);
                    Log.d("test", myImage.getImageName());
                    Log.d("test", myImage.getId());
                    Log.d("test", myImage.getPhoto().toString());
                }
```

I have also tried to use serialiseble for the Image class, still no result.

complete code:

fragment1:

```
package com.example.briefingaboutitapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment;

import com.example.briefingaboutitapp.databinding.FragmentThirdBinding;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import Entities.Image;

public class ThirdFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentThirdBinding binding;

    private ActivityResultLauncher<String> galleryLauncher;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {

        binding = FragmentThirdBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        return binding.getRoot();

    }

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        try {
            Gson gson = new Gson();

                if (gson.fromJson(requireArguments().getString("IMAGE"), Image.class) != null) {
                    Image myImage = gson.fromJson(requireArguments().getString("IMAGE"), Image.class);
                    Log.d("test", myImage.getImageName());
                    Log.d("test", myImage.getId());
                    Log.d("test", myImage.getPhoto().toString());
                }

        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("test", "image still null");
        }

        binding.returnToEditText.setOnClickListener(view1 -> NavHostFragment.findNavController(ThirdFragment.this)
                .navigate(R.id.action_ThirdFragment_to_SecondFragment));

        Button photoPickerButton = view.findViewById(R.id.photo_picker_button);
        galleryLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(),
                result -> {
                    if(result!= null){

                        //package image uri
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("imageURI", result.toString());

                        //navigate to image display and set title with parceled uri
                        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(view);
                        navController.navigate(R.id.pickedImageFragment, bundle);
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Please select an image!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

        photoPickerButton.setOnClickListener(view12 -> galleryLauncher.launch("image/*"));

        binding.submitForm.setOnClickListener(view1 -> {
            Intent goToMainActivity = new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class);
            this.startActivity(goToMainActivity);
            Toast.makeText(this.getContext(),"Article submitted successfully!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }


}
```

fragment2:

```
package com.example.briefingaboutitapp;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;

import com.example.briefingaboutitapp.databinding.FragmentPickedImageBinding;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.util.UUID;

import Entities.Image;

public class PickedImageFragment extends Fragment {
    private FragmentPickedImageBinding binding;
    private Uri imageUri;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {

        binding = FragmentPickedImageBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        return binding.getRoot();


    }

    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        this.imageUri = Uri.parse(requireArguments().getString("imageURI"));

        //get passed image
        ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        imageView.setImageURI(this.imageUri);


        binding.submitMyPhotoButton.setOnClickListener(view1 -> {
            if(binding.photoDescription.getText().toString().trim().equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Pick title/description for photo!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                //create the gotten image class
                String photoName = binding.photoDescription.getText().toString().trim();
                String imageID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                Image myImage = new Image(imageID, photoName, imageUri);

                //bundle it
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("IMAGE", gson.toJson(myImage));

                //send the bundled image on it's way
                NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(view);
                navController.navigate(R.id.ThirdFragment, bundle);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }
}
```

Image class

```
package Entities;

import android.net.Uri;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Image implements Serializable{
    private final String id;
    private final Uri photo;
    private final String imageName;

    public Image(String id, String imageName, Uri photo) {
        this.id = id;
        this.imageName = imageName;
        this.photo = photo;
    }

    public Uri getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }

    public String getImageName() {
        return imageName;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Too much codes and other things in this question. Please ask the specific problem that you face while do the coding. Then it is easy to give solution.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).